# build php array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have a select box where in it has a list of items and he enters value for each selected option and saves it . 
i have written a function like.

```
$('.add_recordings').click(function () {
    if (($('#recordings_name').val() != '') && ($('#recordings_value').val() != '')) {
        if ($('#recordings').val() == '') {
            var result = $('#recordings_name').val() + '=' + $('#recordings_value').val();
            $('#recordings').html(result);

            var result1 = $('#recordings_name').val() + '=>' + $('#recordings_value').val();
            $('#recordings_array').val(result1);
        }
        else {
            var result = ', ' + $('#recordings_name').val() + '=' + $('#recordings_value').val();
            $('#recordings').append(result);

            var result1 = ', ' + $('#recordings_name').val() + '=>' + $('#recordings_value').val();
            alert(result1);
            $('#recordings_array').append(result1);
        }
    }

});
```

the append function for recordings_array is not working, its a input of type text.

what i am trying to do is to build an php array using jquery ,so that it can be passed in $_POST.. is there any better method to do this?

Comment: Do you want to send the data via Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the append function for recordings_array is not working, **its a
>   input of type text**.

why not set its value instead of appending?

```
$('#recordings_array').val(result1);
```

---

Edit

if you want to append value, it's easy on jQuery 1.4

```
$('#recordings_array').val(function(i,val){
    return val + result1; 
    // this will get the current value of the input (val), 
    // add result1, then return the result as the new value of the input
});
```

below jQuery 1.4

```
$('#recordings_array').val($('#recordings_array').val() + result1);
```

Comment: see i need to build and array like a=>b, b=>c so i need an append function to append each of key=>value pair. select box is list of 10 items . he selects 1 options and enters value for it and then he selects 2nd option and enters value for it and clicks on add. so on click of add i need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sending any other data and you send it via Ajax, I would do it totally differently:

Create a global records object (functioning as associative array):

```
var records = {};
```

and you just add the values to this object when the click occurs:

```
$('.add_recordings').click(function () {
    if (($('#recordings_name').val() != '') && ($('#recordings_value').val() != '')) {
            records[$('#recordings_name').val()] = $('#recordings_value').val();
    }
});
```

Then you send it, e.g. with `ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: records,
   success: function(msg){
     /...
   }
});
```

`records` will be transformed to a query string like

```
recordnameA=recordvalue&recordnameB=recordvalue
```

and on the PHP site you already have all these values in an array:

```
$_POST['recordnameA']
```

---

Of course it also works if you sent other data via POST in addition, you can remove this data from the array after processing it with `unset($_POST['otherdata'])`.

---

**Note:** It is only confusing to build the PHP array string on the client side and you would have to evaluate it, e.g. with `eval()`. But you cannot ensure that the string you get only contains an array, the user could have manipulated it and you have a potential security hole.